# What's the best approach for writing an app that sends continuos mails

Tags: email, smtp, send, spam, blacklist

I'm writing an app that sends mails constantly, in general to different users. Like alerts or reminders. Do I need to take care about how many mails I send? Check time intervals between mails?

I currently have a domain, and I'm sending mails via SMTP. I don't want to enter any black lists or anything.

Answer (score 0):

[MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/) is a startup that manages email newsletters; their livelihood depends on them not getting blacklisted or classified as spam.

You might learn some good approaches by reading the guide they wrote on [How To Avoid Spam Filters](http://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/how-to-avoid-spam-filters/). Here's the basic premise:

> Unfortunately, there's not a quick fix. The only way to avoid spam filters is to understand what spam is and how the filters work.

Comment: I'm currently using MailChimp and it's a great tool for sending campaigns. 

But I want to send multiple mails to single users. And I need to integrate it with my current app in PHP.

Comment: @Federico I'd still suggest reading the MailChimp guide, because it should explain how to write your own mail sender.

Comment: @Federico looks like MC has an [api](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/) maybe that will do what you want